# Create link to users created content only

Tags: 8, navigation

I have a content type Business, When a user creates a business and then signs into the site, I have a link called "my business" that when the user clicks on i want it to take them to only their created business.

Not sure what to "link" too for this to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can link to a view, that filters the content type Business and the current user.

This is a similar question for D7, I think both solutions provided there work in D8 the same way:

[Filtering on node whose user ID is equal to the current user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/22427/filtering-on-node-whose-user-id-is-equal-to-the-current-user)

Answer (score 0):

If you create a custom module you can either use [`hook_user_login()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user.api.php/function/hook_user_login/7) or a custom user login form submit handler (see the answers to this [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185483/redirect-user-to-custom-url-after-login-in-drupal)) to conditionally redirect the user.

You can get their most recently created *Business* node using an [EntityFieldQuery](https://www.drupal.org/node/1343708) and redirect them to that using either of the above approaches.