# Why do I get redirected to userpage after login?

Tags: 8, users

I land on the user profile page when I login as user. I would like to land on the front page after login.
How do I achieve that?

This is my basic site settings:

[image]

Comment: That's how the Drupal login was designed, which makes sense. Imagine if ur bank redirected u to the homepage after u logged in. So ur the weird one.

Comment: @No Sssweat - I don't think the actual request is strange. IMHO, it should be something that's easily configurable. Here's another scenario - you're logging into an ecommerce store, it would be strange to push the user to their account page, rather than their basket or the checkout page, right?

Comment: Already answered here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/185483/redirect-user-to-custom-url-after-login-in-drupal and here http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/195170/redirect-after-user-login

Comment: @BrynJ right, I was just trolling with the "weird" part. Better yet, in some cases, send them to the page they where in prior to the login.